Spouses dancing - sources
Looking for literally any statements or discussion from Chazal regarding spouses dancing together, privately.

https://ascentofsafed.com/cgi-bin/ascent.cgi?Name=1016-35

Why would you think there are any and why are you looking for such sources? Just curious

In terms of what - Halacha?  What's the problem?

@MosesSupposes in terms of literally anything :) I like the idea of spouses dancing, and I want to know if the Torah has an reference at all to it, whether it be a maaseh, a halacha, a mussar - anything. I am bemused that in all my years of learning, I've never seen anything and am also genuinely curious if there is anything. If not, why not?

@Yoreinu good question - see my previous comment
